# Groovy: How to convert XML with mixed content

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm converting data from one file to another syntax. The task of the program is to take the data from the source files and dump into into the intermediate template file, thus creating a new file.

The problem is that I am having trouble with mixed content.

**Source Files**

source file 1:

```
  <para>This para is fine</para>
```

source file 2:

```
  <para><emph>This</emph> para is also fine</para>
```

source file 3:

```
  <para>This para is <emph>not</emph> fine</para>
```

**Intermediate template file**

targetPara.xml:

```
<p></p>
```

targetEmph.xml:

```
<b></b>
```

**Output Files**

target file 1:

```
<p>This para is fine</p>
```

target file 2:

```
<p><b>This</b> para is also fine</p>
```

target file 3:

```
<p>This para is not fine</p>
```

**Groovy code**

```
class Para {

    String getNode(Node sourceNode) {

        GPathResult targetNode = new XmlSlurper(false, false, false ).parse(new File("C:/targetPara.xml"))

        try {
            sourceNode.children().each { Node tag ->
                if(tag.name()=="emph") {
                    Emph childElement = new Emph()
                    String childNode = childElement.getNode(tag)

                    GPathResult child = new XmlSlurper(false, false ).parseText(childNode)
                    targetNode.appendNode(child)
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            targetNode.appendNode(sourceNode.text())
        }
        return XmlUtil.serialize(targetNode)

    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't XSLT be a better fit for this job?

Comment: The idea behind the target syntax is that it is dynamic and customizable by the end user. Storing the transformation and syntax into XSLT would cause our end users to rely on the developer(s) to make small changes (e.g. one user may wish to set targetPara.xml to contain <p style="acme"></p>). I agree that XSLT would be a good tool to use, however given that we want to expose the end result syntax to users, it makes it hard to sell.